# Develop a Chrome extension that overrides SSL certificate exception for a self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension

I frequently access a trusted website that uses a self signed certificate. Every time I access it I need to click - through the SSL error page. I know that it is possible to do some manual settings and add the certificate to the list of Chrome's trusted certificate list. As a self learning fun exercise, I decided to create an extension that does the same thing on a click.

I have already gone through Chrome Developer's guide at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html and have read a couple of other blogs, but I am unable to get an idea on how to implement this extension.

I want to know appropriate JavaScript Classes/ Chrome developer tools/ learning resources/ tutorials that can be used to implement this. I would like to point out that I am an undergraduate student and the concept of SSL/TLS errors and extension development is new to me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As pointed out, there is no provision in extension API to achieve it. Further  latest release of Chrome takes care of this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is available as an extension API, pinning certificates.