# chrome extension bypass certificate exception

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to write a chrome extension that will bypass certificate errors automatically?

I am dealing with automation scripts that deal 100% of the time with self-signed certificates coming from appliance-type web servers. The browser wont/cant be used for regular internet navigation. Is this possible?

Comment: Apparently, this is not possible. As stated in this related [SO post 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507712/develop-a-chrome-extension-that-overrides-ssl-certificate-exception-for-a-self-s) and [SO post 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084128/chrome-extension-that-overrides-ssl-certificate-error-for-self-signed-certificat?rq=1), it is not possible to bypass certificate exception automatically. You have to add manually the certificates, see [superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/41937) for additional information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, you should write that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible. As stated in this related [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507712/develop-a-chrome-extension-that-overrides-ssl-certificate-exception-for-a-self-s) and [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084128/chrome-extension-that-overrides-ssl-certificate-error-for-self-signed-certificat?rq=1), it is not possible to bypass certificate exception automatically. You have to add manually the certificates, see [superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/41937) for additional information. Hope this helps.